# When Binding Data from a Service GET call to Gridview, cant select only certain columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am calling a service as per:

```
IList<Quotes> objUserDetails = new List<Quotes>();
objUserDetails = objService.GetQuote();
```

Problem is when I bind it to a gridview:

```
GridView1.DataSource = objUserDetails;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

in the gridview I get all the columns in list Quotes even though I only want 4 columns.

I cant edit the list Quotes as it is used elsewhere for updating the webservice, and I can't bind to a datasource in the code as it has to be dynamic because it's calling a webservice.

Any ideas? being pulling my teeth out on this one, and only have two teeth left! lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this answered using the following code from another website's forum (ASp.net). Couldn't believe how simple it was. Thanks all the same. 
var fourColList = objUserDetails.Select(x => new { Col1 = x.H_Item, Col2 = x.H_QuoteRef, Col3 = x.T_CSQty, Col4 = x.T_Days }).ToList();
        GridView1.DataSource = fourColList;
Just wanted to complete it here in case anyone else comes across the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `GridVew` declaration in markup, since you are seeing all of the columns from the query, then I am saying your `AutoGenerateColumns` property is set to true, like this:

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="True"...
```

If you wish to not have all columns automatically returned, then you need to set this property to false, like this:

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="True"...
```

Now, since you have said to not have the data decide on what columns get rendered, you need to tell the `GridView` what columns you want via the `Columns` markup.

Read [MSDN Documentation for GridView.Columns Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx)

Comment: HI Karl, thank you for that. I tried that, but couldn't figure out how to bind the data without first converting the ilist into something else, which was messy.. am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try `DataBinder.Eval(PropertyName)`, where `PropertyName` is in quotes and is a public property of your Quotes class?

Comment: HI Karl, sorry for sounding daft, but what do I put in to the datasource ID? I tried objUserDetails, but it throws error: System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The DataSourceID of 'GridView1' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A control with ID 'objUserDetails' could not be found.
  Source=System.Web
  ErrorCode=-2147467259 Thank-you Karl.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? Still stumped.

Comment: You don't need a datasourceid, I have edited the answer. You are already binding to your IList<T> source.

Comment: I had already tried that method before too.. It complains that "Service.Quotes[] does not contain H_Item as one of its properties" H_Item is definitely a property of Quotes. Thats what initially took me down the conversion route, but that is really untidy.

Comment: Is `H_Item` a public property?

Comment: Its is a public property of Quotes (in fact I am using it in another class that updates the service which i will append on the bottom for reference), but I think the issue is when I use IList<Quotes> objUserDetails = new List<Quotes>(); I dont think it is recognised as a property of iList. Surely there is a way to do it without converting though?  the update example is     protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Quotes quoteInfo = new Quotes();
        quoteInfo.H_Item = txtItem.Text;
 string result = objService.UpdateQuoteDetails(quoteInfo);

Comment: Can you post your entire code, along with a dummy implementation of the service to return hard-coded data?

Comment: Cant do that at present as the thing is quite big and I will need to sift through it to see what bits are necessary to put up. But will do Karl, thank you